Simplification of inner product
From https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.12317 how is the simplification of equation (2.16) obtained?

Let $g(x),p(x)$ be real functions and $\lambda$ complex. Consider the expression $\langle g, (-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \lambda I)^{-1}g\rangle-\langle g, (-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} +(p+ \lambda I))^{-1}g\rangle$. I want to show this simplifies to, as stated in the paper, $$\langle (-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + (p+\overline{\lambda})I)^{-1}g,p(\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \lambda I)^{-1}g\rangle$$
However, I do not see how one applies the properties of an inner product to get this.

The first term has $\overline{\lambda}$, not $\lambda$, in the paper.

@stoic-santiago I've updated accordingly.

We clarify the notation a bit: Let $A = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \lambda I$, $B = p$. Then the simplification in question is just:
$$\langle g, A^{-1}g \rangle - \langle g, (A + B)^{-1}g \rangle = \langle (A^\ast + B)^{-1}g, BA^{-1}g \rangle$$
Where $B$ is self-adjoint. This just follows from a direct calculation:
$$\begin{split}
\langle g, A^{-1}g \rangle - \langle g, (A + B)^{-1}g \rangle &= \langle (A^\ast + B)(A^\ast + B)^{-1}g, A^{-1}g \rangle - \langle (A^\ast + B)^{-1}g, g \rangle\\
&= \langle (A^\ast + B)^{-1}g, (A + B)A^{-1}g \rangle - \langle (A^\ast + B)^{-1}g, g \rangle\\
&= \langle (A^\ast + B)^{-1}g, (I + BA^{-1} - I)g \rangle\\
&= \langle (A^\ast + B)^{-1}g, BA^{-1}g \rangle
\end{split}$$

Could you clarify what property was used for the second line? That looks like you took the conjugate of $A^* + B$ and put it into the second spot.

@KZ-Spectra Yes, the conjugate of $A^\ast + B$ is $A + B$ since $B$ is self-adjoint ($p$ is a real-valued function).

But why can it be placed into the second slot of the first inner product?

@KZ-Spectra For any operator $T$ and any vectors $h$ and $k$, by definition of adjoints, $\langle Th, k \rangle = \langle h, T^\ast k \rangle$. I’m simply applying this to $T = A^\ast + B$, $h = (A^\ast + B)^{-1}g$, and $k = A^{-1}g$.

Ah, I fully understand now. Thank you very much.

Switch to Fourier transform  representation in $\mathit {L} ^2(\mathbf k)$
The derivative operator maps to the multiplication operator,
$$\int \mathit {F} (g)(k)^\star \  \left(\frac{1}{k^2+\lambda \
}-\frac{1}{k^2+\lambda +p}\right) \ \mathit F(g)(k)\ dk$$
multiple derivatives to powers, analytic functions by multiple applications to analytic functions by powers of $\mathbf k.$
The difference is factoring as
$$\frac{1}{k^2+\lambda }-\frac{1}{k^2+\lambda +p} =\frac{p}{(k^2 + \lambda) (k^2 + p + \lambda)}=\frac{1}{k^2 + \lambda} \ \frac{p}{k^2 + p + \lambda}$$
Now you may distribute the product of rationals over the two vectors $\mathit F( g)$ in $\mathit L^2$
$$\int \mathit {F} (g)(k)^\star \  \frac{1}{k^2 + \lambda} \ \frac{p}{k^2 + p + \lambda} \ \mathit F(g)(k)\ dk =\int \left(\mathit {F} (g)(k) \  \frac{1}{k^2 + \lambda ^\star} \right)^\star  \ \frac{p} {k^2 + p + \lambda} \ \mathit F(g)(k)\ dk$$
and transform back to the $\mathbf k*\mathit F(g)(\mathbf k) \to -i \partial_{\mathbf x} g(\mathbf x)m \quad k^2\to -\partial_{x,x}$-representation
$$=\int\left(  \frac{1}{\lambda^\star- \partial_{x,x}  } g(x)\right)^\star \   \frac{p}{\lambda-\partial_{x,x}} \ g(x)\ dx  $$

Thank you. Can you tell me how you write the integral you have there?

You want the TeX form:  \int \mathit {F} (g)(k)\  \left(\frac{1}{k^2+\lambda 
}-\frac{1}{k^2+\lambda +p}\right) \ \mathit F(g)(k)\ dk

sorry, but I had meant how does taking the fourier transform of the difference of those inner products give the integral you had written.
